# Ubuntu computer spinning on simple tasks - similar Windows computer handles same tasks easily

Tags: 18.04, performance

My home computer is running Ubuntu 18.04.  I have a similarly configured work computer that is running Windows 10.  Both computers are about 4 year old Dell computers.  On my Ubuntu computer - when I visit some websites, scroll around Google Earth, process data - the hard drive starts spinning wildly and the fan kicks on as if the computer is struggling.  I have noticed that my Windows computer does not have he same issues doing the same tasks.  The fan never kicks on when visiting websites, only when I am processing loads of image files.

I have ensured that the components of my Ubuntu computer are free of dust and that the vents are unblocked.

Why does my Ubuntu computer seem to struggle so much on simple tasks?

Here are the stats for the Windows 10 computer.

[image]

And here is the Ubuntu computer...

```
        H/W path               Device      Class          Description
=============================================================
system         XPS 8920 (07DC)
/0  bus            0VHXCD
/0/0                               memory         64KiB BIOS
/0/27                              memory         32GiB System Memory
/0/27/0                            memory         8GiB DIMM DDR4 Synchronous Unbuffered 
(Unregiste
/0/27/1                            memory         8GiB DIMM DDR4 Synchronous Unbuffered (Unregiste
/0/27/2                            memory         8GiB DIMM DDR4 Synchronous Unbuffered (Unregiste
/0/27/3                            memory         8GiB DIMM DDR4 Synchronous Unbuffered (Unregiste
/0/2d                              memory         256KiB L1 cache
/0/2e                              memory         1MiB L2 cache
/0/2f                              memory         8MiB L3 cache
/0/30                              processor      Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-7700 CPU @ 3.60GHz
/0/100                             bridge         Xeon E3-1200 v6/7th Gen Core Processor Host Brid
/0/100/1                           bridge         Xeon E3-1200 v5/E3-1500 v5/6th Gen Core Processo
/0/100/1/0                         display        GP106 [GeForce GTX 1060 6GB]
/0/100/1/0.1                       multimedia     GP106 High Definition Audio Controller
/0/100/2                           display        HD Graphics 630
/0/100/14                          bus            200 Series/Z370 Chipset Family USB 3.0 xHCI Cont
/0/100/14/0            usb1        bus            xHCI Host Controller
/0/100/14/0/1          scsi5       storage        Flash Card Reader/Writer
/0/100/14/0/1/0.0.0    /dev/sdb    disk           Card  Reader
/0/100/14/0/1/0.0.0/0  /dev/sdb    disk           
/0/100/14/0/5                      input          PS/2+USB Mouse
/0/100/14/0/8                      communication  Bluetooth wireless interface
/0/100/14/0/c                      printer        Officejet 5740 series
/0/100/14/0/e                      input          Dell KB216 Wired Keyboard
/0/100/14/1            usb2        bus            xHCI Host Controller
/0/100/15                          generic        200 Series PCH Serial IO I2C Controller #0
/0/100/15.1                        generic        200 Series PCH Serial IO I2C Controller #1
/0/100/16                          communication  200 Series PCH CSME HECI #1
/0/100/17                          storage        200 Series PCH SATA controller [AHCI mode]
/0/100/1c                          bridge         200 Series PCH PCI Express Root Port #2
/0/100/1c/0                        bus            ASM1142 USB 3.1 Host Controller
/0/100/1c/0/0          usb3        bus            xHCI Host Controller
/0/100/1c/0/1          usb4        bus            xHCI Host Controller
/0/100/1c.2                        bridge         200 Series PCH PCI Express Root Port #3
/0/100/1c.2/0          wlp3s0      network        Wireless 3165
/0/100/1c.3                        bridge         200 Series PCH PCI Express Root Port #4
/0/100/1c.3/0          enp4s0      network        QCA8171 Gigabit Ethernet
/0/100/1d                          bridge         200 Series PCH PCI Express Root Port #9
/0/100/1d/0                        storage        XG4 NVMe SSD Controller
/0/100/1e                          generic        200 Series/Z370 Chipset Family Serial IO UART Co
/0/100/1f                          bridge         200 Series PCH LPC Controller (Z270)
/0/100/1f.2                        memory         Memory controller
/0/100/1f.3                        multimedia     200 Series PCH HD Audio
/0/100/1f.4                        bus            200 Series/Z370 Chipset Family SMBus Controller
/0/1                   scsi1       storage        
/0/1/0.0.0             /dev/sda    disk           2TB ST32000644NS
/0/1/0.0.0/1           /dev/sda1   volume         127MiB reserved partition
/0/1/0.0.0/2           /dev/sda2   volume         1862GiB EXT4 volume
/0/2                   scsi2       storage        
/0/2/0.0.0             /dev/cdrom  disk           DVD+-RW GU90N
/0/2/0.0.0/0           /dev/cdrom  disk           
/0/3                   scsi6       storage        
/0/3/0.0.0             /dev/sdc    disk           Officejet 5740 s
/0/3/0.0.0/0           /dev/sdc    disk   


01:00.0 VGA compatible controller: NVIDIA Corporation GP106 [GeForce GTX 1060 6GB] (rev a1)
```

Here is the output from the graphics card...

```
ubuntu-drivers devices
== /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:01.0/0000:01:00.0 ==
modalias : pci:v000010DEd00001C03sv00001462sd00008C94bc03sc00i00
vendor   : NVIDIA Corporation
model    : GP106 [GeForce GTX 1060 6GB]
driver   : nvidia-driver-418-server - distro non-free
driver   : nvidia-driver-390 - distro non-free
driver   : nvidia-driver-450 - distro non-free
driver   : nvidia-driver-455 - distro non-free recommended
driver   : nvidia-driver-450-server - distro non-free
driver   : nvidia-driver-440-server - distro non-free
driver   : xserver-xorg-video-nouveau - distro free builtin

== /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1c.2/0000:03:00.0 ==
modalias : pci:v00008086d00003165sv00008086sd00004410bc02sc80i00
vendor   : Intel Corporation
model    : Wireless 3165
manual_install: True
driver   : backport-iwlwifi-dkms - distro free
```

Here is the output from $free
[image]

And this from $top
[image]

And here is an example of the output from /var/log/syslog

```
Dec  5 09:47:48 gerry pcmanfm[2256]: x-terminal-emulator has very limited support, consider choose another terminal

Dec  5 09:47:51 gerry kernel: [75656.732362] pcieport 0000:00:1c.2: AER: Corrected error received: 0000:00:1c.2

Dec  5 09:47:51 gerry kernel: [75656.732381] pcieport 0000:00:1c.2: AER: PCIe Bus Error: severity=Corrected, type=Physical Layer, (Receiver ID)

Dec  5 09:47:51 gerry kernel: [75656.732390] pcieport 0000:00:1c.2: AER:   device [8086:a292] error status/mask=00000001/00002000

Dec  5 09:47:51 gerry kernel: [75656.732452] pcieport 0000:00:1c.2: AER:    [ 0] RxErr                 

Dec  5 09:47:57 gerry kernel: [75662.728801] pcieport 0000:00:1c.2: AER: Corrected error received: 0000:00:1c.2

Dec  5 09:47:57 gerry kernel: [75662.728816] pcieport 0000:00:1c.2: AER: PCIe Bus Error: severity=Corrected, type=Physical Layer, (Receiver ID)

Dec  5 09:47:57 gerry kernel: [75662.728823] pcieport 0000:00:1c.2: AER:   device [8086:a292] error status/mask=00000001/00002000

Dec  5 09:47:57 gerry kernel: [75662.728828] pcieport 0000:00:1c.2: AER:    [ 0] RxErr                 

Dec  5 09:47:57 gerry kernel: [75663.219021] pcieport 0000:00:1c.2: AER: Corrected error received: 0000:00:1c.2

Dec  5 09:47:57 gerry kernel: [75663.219035] pcieport 0000:00:1c.2: AER: PCIe Bus Error: severity=Corrected, type=Physical Layer, (Receiver ID)

Dec  5 09:47:57 gerry kernel: [75663.219042] pcieport 0000:00:1c.2: AER:   device [8086:a292] error status/mask=00000001/00002000

Dec  5 09:47:57 gerry kernel: [75663.219047] pcieport 0000:00:1c.2: AER:    [ 0] RxErr                 

Dec  5 09:48:03 gerry kernel: [75668.468657] pcieport 0000:00:1c.2: AER: Corrected error received: 0000:00:1c.2

Dec  5 09:48:03 gerry kernel: [75668.468671] pcieport 0000:00:1c.2: AER: PCIe Bus Error: severity=Corrected, type=Physical Layer, (Receiver ID)

Dec  5 09:48:03 gerry kernel: [75668.468679] pcieport 0000:00:1c.2: AER:   device [8086:a292] error status/mask=00000001/00002000

Dec  5 09:48:03 gerry kernel: [75668.468684] pcieport 0000:00:1c.2: AER:    [ 0] RxErr                 

Dec  5 09:48:03 gerry kernel: [75668.730175] pcieport 0000:00:1c.2: AER: Corrected error received: 0000:00:1c.2

Dec  5 09:48:03 gerry kernel: [75668.730190] pcieport 0000:00:1c.2: AER: PCIe Bus Error: severity=Corrected, type=Physical Layer, (Receiver ID)

Dec  5 09:48:03 gerry kernel: [75668.730197] pcieport 0000:00:1c.2: AER:   device [8086:a292] error status/mask=00000001/00002000

Dec  5 09:48:03 gerry kernel: [75668.730201] pcieport 0000:00:1c.2: AER:    [ 0] RxErr                 

Dec  5 09:48:09 gerry kernel: [75674.728631] pcieport 0000:00:1c.2: AER: Corrected error received: 0000:00:1c.2

Dec  5 09:48:09 gerry kernel: [75674.728641] pcieport 0000:00:1c.2: AER: PCIe Bus Error: severity=Corrected, type=Physical Layer, (Receiver ID)

Dec  5 09:48:09 gerry kernel: [75674.728645] pcieport 0000:00:1c.2: AER:   device [8086:a292] error status/mask=00000001/00002000

Dec  5 09:48:09 gerry kernel: [75674.728648] pcieport 0000:00:1c.2: AER:    [ 0] RxErr                 

Dec  5 09:48:13 gerry kernel: [75678.968692] pcieport 0000:00:1c.2: AER: Corrected error received: 0000:00:1c.2

Dec  5 09:48:13 gerry kernel: [75678.968706] pcieport 0000:00:1c.2: AER: PCIe Bus Error: severity=Corrected, type=Physical Layer, (Receiver ID)

Dec  5 09:48:13 gerry kernel: [75678.968713] pcieport 0000:00:1c.2: AER:   device [8086:a292] error status/mask=00000001/00002000

Dec  5 09:48:13 gerry kernel: [75678.968718] pcieport 0000:00:1c.2: AER:    [ 0] RxErr                 


Dec  5 09:48:14 gerry pcmanfm.desktop[2256]: gedit 'file:///var/log/syslog'
```

Here is the output from lspci -tv
[image]

Here are some of the last lines from /var/log/syslog

```
Dec  5 11:46:16 gerry dbus-daemon[1050]: [system] Successfully activated service 'org.freedesktop.hostname1'
Dec  5 11:46:16 gerry systemd[1]: Starting Hostname Service...
Dec  5 11:46:16 gerry systemd[1]: Started Hostname Service.
Dec  5 11:50:08 gerry dbus-daemon[6338]: [session uid=1000 pid=6338] Activating via systemd: service name='org.gnome.Terminal' unit='gnome-terminal-server.service' requested by ':1.126' (uid=1000 pid=14593 comm="/usr/bin/gnome-terminal.real " label="unconfined")
Dec  5 11:50:08 gerry systemd[6295]: Starting GNOME Terminal Server...
Dec  5 11:50:09 gerry dbus-daemon[6338]: [session uid=1000 pid=6338] Successfully activated service 'org.gnome.Terminal'
Dec  5 11:50:09 gerry systemd[6295]: Started GNOME Terminal Server.
Dec  5 11:51:22 gerry thunar[9170]: can't init metadata tree /home/gerry/.local/share/gvfs-metadata/root: open: Permission denied
Dec  5 11:51:22 gerry thunar[9170]: message repeated 9 times: [ can't init metadata tree /home/gerry/.local/share/gvfs-metadata/root: open: Permission denied]
Dec  5 11:51:22 gerry thunar[9170]: can't init metadata tree /home/gerry/.local/share/gvfs-metadata/home: open: Permission denied
Dec  5 11:51:22 gerry gvfsd-metadata[9177]: g_udev_device_has_property: assertion 'G_UDEV_IS_DEVICE (device)' failed
Dec  5 11:51:22 gerry gvfsd-metadata[9177]: g_udev_device_has_property: assertion 'G_UDEV_IS_DEVICE (device)' failed
Dec  5 11:51:22 gerry thunar[9170]: can't init metadata tree /home/gerry/.local/share/gvfs-metadata/root: open: Permission denied
Dec  5 11:51:22 gerry thunar[9170]: message repeated 7 times: [ can't init metadata tree /home/gerry/.local/share/gvfs-metadata/root: open: Permission denied]
Dec  5 11:51:22 gerry gvfsd-metadata[9177]: g_udev_device_has_property: assertion 'G_UDEV_IS_DEVICE (device)' failed
Dec  5 11:51:22 gerry gvfsd-metadata[9177]: g_udev_device_has_property: assertion 'G_UDEV_IS_DEVICE (device)' failed
Dec  5 11:51:22 gerry thunar[9170]: can't init metadata tree /home/gerry/.local/share/gvfs-metadata/root: open: Permission denied
Dec  5 11:51:22 gerry gvfsd-metadata[9177]: g_udev_device_has_property: assertion 'G_UDEV_IS_DEVICE (device)' failed
Dec  5 11:51:22 gerry gvfsd-metadata[9177]: g_udev_device_has_property: assertion 'G_UDEV_IS_DEVICE (device)' failed
Dec  5 11:51:22 gerry thunar[9170]: can't init metadata tree /home/gerry/.local/share/gvfs-metadata/root: open: Permission denied
Dec  5 11:51:22 gerry thunar[9170]: message repeated 3 times: [ can't init metadata tree /home/gerry/.local/share/gvfs-metadata/root: open: Permission denied]
Dec  5 11:51:22 gerry gvfsd-metadata[9177]: g_udev_device_has_property: assertion 'G_UDEV_IS_DEVICE (device)' failed
Dec  5 11:51:22 gerry gvfsd-metadata[9177]: g_udev_device_has_property: assertion 'G_UDEV_IS_DEVICE (device)' failed
Dec  5 11:51:22 gerry thunar[9170]: can't init metadata tree /home/gerry/.local/share/gvfs-metadata/root: open: Permission denied
Dec  5 11:51:22 gerry thunar[9170]: message repeated 6 times: [ can't init metadata tree /home/gerry/.local/share/gvfs-metadata/root: open: Permission denied]
Dec  5 11:51:31 gerry thunar[9170]: can't init metadata tree /home/gerry/.local/share/gvfs-metadata/root: open: Permission denied
Dec  5 11:51:33 gerry thunar[9170]: message repeated 91 times: [ can't init metadata tree /home/gerry/.local/share/gvfs-metadata/root: open: Permission denied]
Dec  5 11:51:52 gerry gedit[14666]: can't init metadata tree /home/gerry/.local/share/gvfs-metadata/root: open: Permission denied
Dec  5 11:51:52 gerry thunar[9170]: can't init metadata tree /home/gerry/.local/share/gvfs-metadata/root: open: Permission denied
```

dkms has been installed but dkms status return nothing.

Here is a screenshot of Software and Updates:
[image]

Here is the output from lshw -C network:

```
sudo lshw -C network
  *-network                 
   description: Wireless interface
   product: Wireless 3165
   vendor: Intel Corporation
   physical id: 0
   bus info: pci@0000:03:00.0
   logical name: wlp3s0
   version: 79
   serial: 70:1c:e7:e0:a3:3a
   width: 64 bits
   clock: 33MHz
   capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list ethernet physical wireless
   configuration: broadcast=yes driver=iwlwifi driverversion=5.4.0-52-generic firmware=29.1044073957.0 ip=192.168.1.6 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11
   resources: irq:147 memory:df300000-df301fff
  *-network
   description: Ethernet interface
   product: QCA8171 Gigabit Ethernet
   vendor: Qualcomm Atheros
   physical id: 0
   bus info: pci@0000:04:00.0
   logical name: enp4s0
   version: 10
   serial: 14:b3:1f:07:9f:ef
   size: 1Gbit/s
   capacity: 1Gbit/s
   width: 64 bits
   clock: 33MHz
   capabilities: pm pciexpress msi msix bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt-fd autonegotiation
   configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=alx duplex=full ip=192.168.1.5 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes port=twisted pair speed=1Gbit/s
   resources: irq:19 memory:df200000-df23ffff ioport:d000(size=128)
```

here

After upgrading to 20.04 my problem is back.  Here are the current drivers.

```
$ ubuntu-drivers devices
WARNING:root:_pkg_get_support nvidia-driver-390: package has      invalid Support Legacyheader, cannot determine support level
== /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:01.0/0000:01:00.0 ==
modalias : pci:v000010DEd00001C03sv00001462sd00008C94bc03sc00i00
vendor   : NVIDIA Corporation
model    : GP106 [GeForce GTX 1060 6GB]
driver   : nvidia-driver-470-server - distro non-free
driver   : nvidia-driver-470 - distro non-free recommended
driver   : nvidia-driver-390 - distro non-free
driver   : nvidia-driver-460 - distro non-free
driver   : nvidia-driver-460-server - distro non-free
driver   : nvidia-driver-450-server - distro non-free
driver   : nvidia-driver-495 - distro non-free
driver   : nvidia-driver-418-server - distro non-free
driver   : xserver-xorg-video-nouveau - distro free builtin
```

Comment: `dstat` is a good tool for seeing a bit of what's happening. `sudo apt install dstat` then in a wide terminal `dstat -v --top-io` and keep an eye on it when the disk goes mad. You should see in the last column show what's causing the disk IO.

Comment: There are many possible causes. During a slowdown, check `top` for heavy CPU usage. Check `free` for heavy RAM usage and swapping. And read your `/var/log/syslog` around the time of a slowdown for error messages and other possible clues. Add what you discover to your Question above.

Comment: Do you have the recommended nVidia driver installed? And if you already had one installed, did you completely purge old driver before installing new correct driver? Otherwise conflicts & issues. #What is installed
`dkms status`   If purge required: `sudo apt-get remove --purge nvidia-*` and install. `sudo ubuntu-drivers autoinstall`

Comment: @oldfred  I did try upgrading and reinstalling the nvidia drivers.  I did not remove any old ones.  What is dkms status?  That returns a command not found message in the terminal.

Comment: I thought dkms was installed by default. If not did it not say you can install it? `sudo apt install dkms`

Comment: You're having AER errors. Edit your question and show me `lspci -tv`. It may be a comm card. Why are you using a backport driver? Show me `dkms status`. Also show me screenshot(s) of the `Disks` **SMART Data** scrollable window. In the `top` command, your gnome-shell usage is way high. What does it look like when the computer is idel? Start comments to me with @heynnema  or I'll miss them.

Comment: Also show me `grep -i FPDMA /var/log/syslog*`.

Comment: @heynnema I have added some lines of the syslog and the lspci -tv output to my question.  I do not know what a backport driver is or why that is a questionable problem. Disk SMART Data is grayed-out on the ss hard drivewith the OS.  I can run SMART data on the optical (storage drive) will that help?

Comment: Your AER errors are on device 1c.2, and I was right, that's your wireless card. It's also using the backport-iwlwifi-dkms driver that I was asking about. In order to write you a proper answer, I need all of the data available. You didn't show me the SMART Data, or the `grep` that I asked for. Also show me a screenshot of `Software & Updates` **Additional Drivers** tab, and lastly `sudo lshw -C network`.

Comment: In the `top` window, what is the gnome-shell CPU% when the computer is idle?

Comment: @heynnema - I have added the screen shot from Software and Updates.  I have added the output from lshw -C network.  When I enter grep -i FPDMA... into the terminal nothing happens.  I did post the last few lines from syslog though.  When idle the CPU% bounces between 2.5% to 3.3%.  Smart Data is grayed out for the drive with the OS.  Do you want to see Smart Data for my 2TB drive?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have multiple problems on your computer. We'll hit the most obvious ones first.

**AER errors**

Your AER (Advanced Error Reporting) errors are on device 1c.2, and I was right, that's your Intel 3165 wireless card.

`sudo -H gedit /etc/default/grub` # edit this file

Find:

`GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash"`

Change it to:

`GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash pci=noaer"`

`sudo update-grub` # update GRUB

`reboot` # reboot the computer

**Nvidia GTX 1060**

You're currently using the low-performance nouveau video driver. You should select this choice in `Software & Updates` **Additional Drivers** tab...

[image]

**Note**: The Nvidia drivers can cause problems, so assure that you have good data backups BEFORE changing the driver.

Comment: Thanks.  That seem to do the trick.  No troubles switching graphics drivers either.